# Eslint ignoring my rule settings "no-unused-vars"

Tags: eslint, typescript-eslint

Still getting this rule reported as an error when I run eslint.  This is after I have set `no-unused-vars` and `@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars` to warning in .eslintrc file.

I have tried both `"no-unused-vars" : 1` and `"no-unused-vars" : "warn"` to no effect.

Why is eslint ignoring my rule settings?

.eslintrc file

```
{
  "root": true,
  "env": {
    "node": false,
    "browser": true
  },
  "globals": {
    "google": true,
    "process": true
  },
  "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaVersion": "latest",
    "requireConfigFile": false
  },
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["*.{ts,tsx}"],
      "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
      "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint"],
      "extends": ["plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"] // needed for ts
    }
  ],
  "rules": {
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": 1, // < ----- this wont set it to a warning
    "no-unused-vars": 1, // < ----- this wont set it to a warning, still error
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `"overrides"` > `"extends": ["plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"]` is setting the rule to a new setting for you. `overrides` does what the name suggests: it *overrides* the base settings. Move the `rules` object into the `"overrides"`.

```js
"overrides": [
    {
      // etc. etc.
      "extends": ["plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"],
      "rules": { /* reconfigure rules here */ }
    }
  ]
```

See https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/configuration-files#configuration-based-on-glob-patterns for documentation on overrides in the legacy ESLint config file format that you're using.

The [new ESLint "flat" config file format](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/configuration-files-new) makes a lot of this more clear.